# Rails models with before/after filters and observers, is it possible to ignore these hooks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If a model  has before/after hooks, and possibly some observers for other events, is it possible to somehow ONLY perform a save/update operation on the model and skip any/all of these hooks that will fire?

e.g. I perform a save, and somehow tell my model to ignore any after_save events, and don't notify the observer of this save as I don't want it to fire whatever it usuall does.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the skip_callback method for not to execute the callbacks. For eg:

**User.skip_callback("create",:after,:send_confirmation_email)** will skip the callback with the name send_confirmation_email which is configured on after_create.

You can set the same back by: **User.set_callback("create",:after,:send_confirmation_email)**

Answer (score 3):

I use `update_all` for such requirements.

```
# update the name and price of product with id 23
Product.update_all({:name => "foo bar", :price => 25}, {:id => 23})
```

I have also used this technique before:

```
product.name = "foo"
product.description = "bar"
changes = product.changes.inject({}){|h, v| h[v[0]]=v[1][1];h}
Product.update_all(changes, :id => product)
product.reload # for good measure..
```

Here, you are operating on the object in a normal fashion, and when you are ready to update the object you extract the changed attributes. This eliminates the need for hard coding the columns to update.

Comment: Updated the answer with additional approach.

Comment: `update_all` is the answer to my prayers. I was calculating live stats using `before_save`, it was a nightmare.